# Can't get a specific element from an array. React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I retrieve an array of data through fetch from an API. In my React Component, when I use mapStateToProps and .map(), I am able to display the contents of the array. However, if I try to get just one element from the array like array[0], it keeps returning undefined.

```
/* HomePage class Component: Ascendent of Banner */
class HomePage extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchMovies();
  }

  render() {
    const movie = this.props.movies[0];

    return (
      <div>
        <Banner movies={this.props.movies} movie={movie} />
        <Movies movies={this.props.movies} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

HomePage.propTypes = {
  fetchMovies: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  movies: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  movies: state.movies.movies
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchMovies }
)(HomePage);












/* Banner class Component: Descendent of HomePage */
class Banner extends Component {
  render() {
    const movieList = this.props.movies.map(movie => {
      return <li>{movie.title}</li>;
    });

    return (
      <div style={styles.BannerContainer}>
        <div style={styles.Banner}>
          <div style={styles.BannerText}>
            <h1 style={styles.BannerTextHeader}>{this.props.movie.title}</h1>
            <p style={styles.BannerTextParagraph}>
              Arthur Curry learns that he is the heir to the underwater kingdom
              of Atlantis, and must step forward to lead his people and be a
              hero to the world.
            </p>

            <ul>{movieList}</ul>

            <Button content={"Check It Out"} />
          </div>

          <div style={styles.BannerImage} />
          <div style={styles.BannerOverlay} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Banner;
```

I expect this.props.movie.title to equal this.props.movies[0].title, but the actual output is an error saying cannot get title of undefined.

Comment: Try `console.log(this.props.movies)` in `render()` to see if movies is `undefined` at any moment of any execution of `render()`. If it is `undefined` at any moment, then attempting to grab a specific item at a specific index will cause an error. You can at minimum use conditional rendering to only attempt to get the item if the array has length greater than zero.

Comment: I get two logs the first with an empty array, and the second with all the data. I'm assuming the second is when the redux store retrieves the data from the API. How would you handle making this.props.movies[0] only attempt once the data has been retrieved from the server? Also, just out of my personal curiosity, why is it that .map() works despite the time it takes of retrieving the data, and movies[0] does not?

Comment: That is the issue. You are attempting to get an item that doesn't exist at a certain moment (even if it's an extremely brief moment) in the rendering. Functions like `map()`, `filter()`, and `reduce()` don't attempt to iterate over any elements in the array if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you access

```
{this.props.movie.title}
```

Like

```
{this.props.movie[0].title}
```

Seems more logical to me. And this might be the solution. 
correct me if i am wrong.

And could you also console.log `{this.props.movie}`

Answer (score 0):

Initially movies may be empty array and since you are accessing zero index position you should check it’s length before accessing zero index.

Change

```
  const movie = this.props.movies[0];
```

To

```
  if(this.props.movies.length){
      const movie = this.props.movies[0];
      console.log(movie);
 }
```

Since movies is always an array so checking directly it’s length will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that this.props.movies is undefined on first render )until you make the call to fetchMovies).

Consider checking if it exists first like this:

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchMovies();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.movies && this.props.movies[0]) {
      const movie = this.props.movies[0];
      return (
        <div>
          <Banner movies={this.props.movies} movie={movie} />
          <Movies movies={this.props.movies} />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I console.log, I get two logs the first with an empty array, and the second with all the data. I'm assuming the second is when the redux store retrieves the data from the API. How would you handle making this.props.movies[0] only attempt once the data has been retrieved from the server? Also, just out of my personal curiosity, why is it that .map() works despite the time it takes of retrieving the data, and movies[0] does not?

Comment: @Scott This condition if (this.props.movies && this.props.movies[0]) { works as same as what OP’s has in his code. Doesn’t resolve the issue

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see that in OP's code. Thank you so much! This fixed everything for me!

Comment: Sorry my comment was to Scott but not to you peter :)